# Vue, Vuex & remote storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

Well a have some value in remote storage (lets say `x`) and `b-form-checkbox` that should control this value. I want to inform user if value actually changed on storage and time when it happens.

So basically I want:

1. When user check/uncheck `b-form-checkbox` I want to change state of `b-form-checkbox`, send async request to the remote storage and show some `b-spinner` to indicate that state isn't actually changed yet.
2. When I receive answer from remote storage:

   - if change was successful just hide `b-spinner`.
   - if change was not successful (timeouted, error on server, etc) I want to change `b-form-checkbox` state back (since value actually doesn't changed on storage) and hide `b-spinner`

What is the silliest way to do int using Vue + Vuex?
Currently I'm doing it this way:

`xChanger.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <b-form-checkbox v-model="xComp" switch>
    {{xComp ? 'On' : 'Off'}}
    <b-spinner v-if="!xSynced"/>
  </b-form-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  export default {
    name: 'XChanger',

    computed: {
      ...mapState(['x']),
      ...mapGetters(['xSynced']),

      xComp: {
        get() { return x.local },
        set(value) {
          if (value != this.x.local) {
            this.setX(value)
          }
        },
      },
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['setX']),
    },
  }
</script>
```

`main.js`

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Axios from 'axios'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    x: {
      remote: null,
      local: null
    },
    getters: {
      xSynced(state) {
        state.x.local === state.x.remote
      }
    },
    actions: {
      async setX(store, value) {
        store.state.x.local = value
        try {
          let response = await Axios.post('http://blah.blah/setX', {x: value});
          if (response.status == 200) {
            store.state.x.remote = value
          }
        } catch (error) {
          store.state.x.local = !value
        }
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      setX(state, value) {
        state.x.local = value
        state.x.remote = value
      }
    }
  },
})
```

But it is too verbose for just one value to be controlled (especially computed property `xComp`). I'm sure that such a simple template should be already solved and has more simple way to implement.

Comment: You can severely simplify the things if you keep the state locally in your component instead of inside Vuex - unless you have a very strong reason to share the state of this particular checkbox among multiple Vue components.

Comment: @IVOGELOV if you take a close to xComp, you will see that it doesn't store state in the component, only use computed property

Comment: @IVOGELOV anyway, can you show me a small example, how you see the better solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```html
<template>
  <b-form-checkbox v-model="x.local" switch>
    {{x.local ? 'On' : 'Off'}}
    <b-spinner v-if="saving"/>
  </b-form-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
  export default 
  {
    name: 'XChanger',
    data: () => ({
      x:
      {
        local: false,
        remote: false,
      },
      saving: false,
    }),
    watch:
    {
      'x.local'(newValue, oldValue)
      {
        if (newValue !== oldValue && newValue !== this.x.remote) 
        {
          this.updateRemote(newValue);
        }
      }
    }
    methods: 
    {
      async updateRemote(value)
      {
        try 
        {
          this.saving = true;
          const response = await Axios.post('http://blah.blah/setX', {x: value});
          if (response.status == 200) 
          {
            this.x.remote = value;
          }
          else
          {
            this.x.local = this.x.remote;
          }
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
          this.x.local = this.x.remote;
        }
        this.saving = false;
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: but... your approach didn't use vuex

Comment: Indeed - and it is much simpler than your example. Do not you prefer simpler and less verbose code instead of more complex one ?

Comment: the problem is that I need Vuex, since this is not only widget that controls remote X

Comment: In this case I doubt you can reduce the verbosity of your current solution.